# should chained calls be used in favor of more explicit assignments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stringio

our team have to snippet like below:

this:

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb').write(foo)
...
```

and this one:

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
tmp = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb')
tmp.write(foo)
...
```

which one is more pythonic?

EDITED:
I have try/catch to do the error handling work, but which one is more pythonic?

Comment: Sparse is better than dense, young grasshopper.

Comment: I'd prefer the version not pictured using the `with` statement, but I'm too lazy to use my mobile device to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is fine. Choose the one you find to be most readable.

Personally, I'd go with the first one, the use of the extra variable doesn't add anything *for me*.

That said, in this context ecatmur is correct that you need to close the `GZipFile` instance after writing all the data to it, as that flushes the compression data to `buf` and adds the gzip CRC and size information. Without this your data is potentially incomplete!

Comment: Especially considering its extremely meaningful name.

Comment: AGREE with what ecatmur commented below. But Martijn Pieters is the ONLY people answered the question with this :   "the use of the extra variable doesn't add anything for me."

Answer (score 11):

You need to close the `GzipFile` object after you are finished with it, so the one-line will not work.  Instead, use a context manager expression:

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb') as tmp:
    tmp.write(foo)
```

The one-liner `gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb').write(foo)` is *extremely dangerous* as it depends on the `GzipFile` being garbage-collected at the end of the expression so that the stream is flushed.  If this fails to occur (e.g. using Jython) then `buf` will not contain the expected result.

Comment: More importantly, closing the `GZipFile` instance is essential for finalizing the compression, and for writing the essential CRC value!

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
Man.eat.work.sleep()
```

Methods chaining are common in ruby/javascript, I think it's more `ruby/javascript style` not `pythonic`.

Comment: Nope, you see it in Python too, in appropriate places. Take a look at SQLAlchemy for example, it is quite common to see chaining there as applying successive filters makes sense when working with SQL data.